Removing And/Or Replacing Geometry In A Sculpt
I've been modeling my first 3D character. After getting to a happy point to where I'd like to retopologize and start UV maps, I realized that at some point I mistakenly joined the legs together. I've been using incremental saves, but the mistake occurred pretty far back so I'd rather not reset so much progress.
When I delete the verts I get an effect that removes a lot of geometry (as seen in my third picture). What is the best way to replace this geometry?
I understand this problem would be tackled differently by different technicians, but please do share your method.




maybe you could hover over one leg, press L key to select it, press H to hide, then select vertices that go across 0 (I'm not sure the character is axis-aligned, judging be what we can see through the ass-hole, I guess it isn't?), and move it exactly to 0 (could set the x coordinate in the numbers panel), and do the same for the other leg, then A, M, B to merge those vertices?

you could use some boolean objects?

If the object is symmetrical, you could just delete half the mesh, fill the hole, remesh it and smooth it out in sculpt mode. You probably want to rework that area anyways because if the geometry is overlapping there it's going to be pretty hard to retopologize it and rigit afterwards.
